# Python call a function using a string from users input

Tags: python, string, function

In this program I am using a a user input to select which alignment the user wnats to align some text, at present I'm usinf if statements like so...

```
if alignment == "Left":
    line = left(new_string)
elif alignment == "Right":
     line = right(new_string)
elif alignment == "Centre":
    line = centre(new_string)
elif alignment == "Fully":
    line = fully(new_string)
else:
    print "Error."
```

However, is there a a way that i can get rid of these statements and just use the users input to call either the left, right, centre, fully functions.

Thanks
JT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map the `alignment` string to functions with a dictionary:

```
alignments = {'Left': left, 'Right': right, 'Centre', centre, 'Fully': fully}

try:
    line = alignments[alignment](new_string)
except KeyError:
    print "Error."
```

Python functions are first-class objects, so you can just store them as values in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
func = globals().get(alignment.lower())
if not func:
    func = locals().get(alignment.lower())
func(new_string)
```

You should make sure that *func* is not *None* at the time it is called.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate it

```
try:
    eval(alignment.lower())(new_string)
except NameError:
    print 'Error'
```

Comment: Yeehaw! Let's input `os.system` then... and as `new_string`... let's take something arbitrary, such as `rm -rf /`, maybe...